# Python Boto: ICMP code (65535) out of range (InvalidParameterValue)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

When creating an AWS security group rule for ICMP using Boto, I received the following error.  I was specifying the port range as 0 to 65535, which is the way to specify all ports for TCP.

> ICMP code (65535) out of range (InvalidParameterValue)

How do I address this?

Answer (score 4):

ICMP does not have ports in the protocol, unlike TCP.  So when making the Boto call, use `-1` for the source and destination ports to avoid the above error.  AWS considers `-1` to be *All*.  Using `0` is also valid, however I haven't verified that it allows all traffic.  It should, given that ICMP has no ports in the protocol.